# How to add indentation for multiline log output

Tags: java, logback

I don't think, I'm the first one who wants this, but I cannot find a configuration for it.

A typical logback log output looks as follows:

```
2021-01-07 13:26:04,639 [MyThread] ERROR [] one.of.my.Classes - Some nice error message : java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: null
    at one.of.my.Classes.method0(Classes:123)
    at one.of.my.Classes.method2(Classes:33)
    ...
Caused by: foo.bar.AnotherException: Blah
    at one.of.my.other.Clazz(Foo.java:693)
    ...
2021-01-07 13:26:04,639 [MyThread]  INFO [] one.of.my.Classes - Multi line info message
Second line
Third line
2021-01-07 13:26:04,639 [MyThread]  INFO [] Some other output
```

To make the output easier to read and also easier to process by log parsers, I'd like to add indentation for lines, which belong to another line, for example:

```
2021-01-07 13:26:04,639 [MyThread] ERROR [] one.of.my.Classes - Some nice error message : java.lang.RuntimeException
    java.lang.RuntimeException: null
        at one.of.my.Classes.method0(Classes:123)
        at one.of.my.Classes.method2(Classes:33)
        ...
    Caused by: foo.bar.AnotherException: Blah
        at one.of.my.other.Clazz(Foo.java:693)
        ...
2021-01-07 13:26:04,639 [MyThread]  INFO [] one.of.my.Classes - Multi line info message
    Second line
    Third line
2021-01-07 13:26:04,639 [MyThread]  INFO [] Some other output
```

So, how can I achieve this with logback?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own custom **[Layout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)** for the logger.

> Layouts are logback components responsible for transforming an incoming event into a String.

It's up to you what to do with the log message. Simple example:

```
public class MyLayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    
    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer(128);
        sbuf.append(event.getTimeStamp() - event.getLoggerContextVO().getBirthTime());
        sbuf.append(" ");
        sbuf.append(event.getLevel());
        sbuf.append(event.getLoggerName());
        sbuf.append(" - ");
        //few indentations for a new line
        sbuf.append(event.getFormattedMessage().replaceAll("\n", "\n  ")); 
        sbuf.append(CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        return sbuf.toString();
    }
}
```

*logback.xml*

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.log.test.layout.MyLayout" />
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```